# DateTime format confusion USA and Europe

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, windows-phone-7

I have this kind of xml where 1st jan and 1st feb is the actually format means dd.mm.yyyy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<eventManager>
    <event>
        <name>brith day0</name>
        <place>home</place>
        <latitude>60.170133</latitude>
        <longitude>24.938428</longitude>
        <date>01.01.2011</date>
        <time>00:00</time>
        <img>birthday.jpg</img>
    </event>
    <event>
        <name>brith day0</name>
        <place>home</place>
        <latitude>60.170133</latitude>
        <longitude>24.938428</longitude>
        <date>01.02.2011</date>
        <time>23:00</time>
        <img>birthday1.jpg</img>
    </event>
</eventManager>
```

Then A class called event which gets all data from above xml event. Now my intention is to check whether two dates are equal or not. For the following case it is true. But it is not true according to above xml format.

```
if (CompareSameMonth(EventList[0]._date, EventList[1]._date)) { }

bool CompareSameMonth(DateTime dt1, DateTime dt2) 
{ 
    bool same = false; 

    Debug.WriteLine("dt1.Month "+dt1.Month.ToString()); // output dt1.Month 1 
    Debug.WriteLine("dt2.Month "+dt2.Month.ToString()); // output dt2.Month 1

    if (dt1.Year == dt2.Year && dt1.Month == dt2.Month) 
        same = true; 

    return same; 
 }
```

How can fix this using c# wp7 problem?

Adding more info how I got XML to EventList:-

public void ParseXml(string content)
        {

```
        m_XMLContent = XDocument.Parse(content);

        var data = from query in m_XMLContent.Descendants("event")
                   select new Event
                   {
                       name = (string)query.Element("name"),
                       place = (string)query.Element("place"),
                       latitude = (double)query.Element("latitude"),
                       longitude = (double)query.Element("longitude"),
                       _date = (DateTime)query.Element("date"),
                       _time = (DateTime)query.Element("time"),
                       imgLink = (string)query.Element("img")
                   };

       EventList.Sort(new DateTimeComparer());

    }

    public class DateTimeComparer : IComparer<Event>
    {
        public int Compare(Event x, Event y)
        {
            return x.date_time.CompareTo(y.date_time);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's impossible to help you, because we don't know how you come from the XML to `EventList` and what values `i` and `j` contain.

Comment: More info added for XML to EventList. i and j is regardless to my problem just 2 array element in loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to store your dates in UTC format to avoid any ambiguity between cultures...

```
<eventManager>
    <event>
        <name>brith day0</name>
        <place>home</place>
        <latitude>60.170133</latitude>
        <longitude>24.938428</longitude>
        <dateTime>2011-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</dateTime>
```

That is of course, assuming you have control over the data :)

If not, I'd recommend converting the localised date times into UTC before you start doing any operations with them.

Comment: That's ISO 8601 (but I think you want `...T00:00:00.000Z`).

Answer (score 4):

For the date parsing and comparsion you have to use CultureInfo object.
For the parsing - US or European culture, for the comparsion - [Invariant culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a.aspx).

```
string s1 = "01.01.2011";
string s2 = "01.02.2011";
bool result;
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
DateTimeStyles styles = DateTimeStyles.None;
DateTime dateOne;
DateTime dateTwo;

if (DateTime.TryParse(s1, culture, styles, out dateOne) && DateTime.TryParse(s2, culture, styles, out dateTwo))
{
    result = dateOne.Equals(dateTow);
}
```

Comment: Seeing the OP I guessed an example on how to compare the actual dates would come handy.